# For loop and printing some values

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have this loop with these variables that prints twice.

```
int size=3;
int num=4;

int i;
for ( i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i )
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", i..?);
    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", i...??);

}
```

How do I make expressions for fprintf so that the loop run 3 times and prints out:

0

2

3

5

6

8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i interpreted the sequence correctly - but at least for the nubers you provided this would work:

```
int size=3;
int num=4;

int i;
for ( i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i )
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", i*3);
    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", i*3+2);
}
```